# Does any python http lib can output the spent time for each step

Tags: python, curl

I want to log some performance information for a python web spider project.
with curl , I can use following command to get the spent time info.

```
curl_format='{
 "time_namelookup": %{time_namelookup},
 "time_connect": %{time_connect},
 "time_appconnect": %{time_appconnect},
 "time_pretransfer": %{time_pretransfer},
 "time_redirect": %{time_redirect},
 "time_starttransfer": %{time_starttransfer},
 "time_total": %{time_total}
}'  

exec curl -w "$curl_format" -o /dev/null -s http://www.google.com
```

If I don't call "curl" command in python code, is there any other python lib/module can get these info?

Answer (score 4):

[PyCurl](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl) can do this

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()

c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://www.google.com')
c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)
c.perform()

print('time_connect: {0}'.format(c.getinfo(c.CONNECT_TIME)))
print('time_pretransfer: {0}'.format(c.getinfo(c.PRETRANSFER_TIME)))
print('time_redirect: {0}'.format(c.getinfo(c.REDIRECT_TIME)))
print('time_starttransfer: {0}'.format(c.getinfo(c.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)))
print('time_total: {0}'.format(c.getinfo(c.TOTAL_TIME)))

c.close()
```